# How to dynamically filter datasets based on their location

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson

I'm trying to achieve the following behaviour with a mongodb query:

- I have documents which have a field `location` and a 2dshere geospatial index on that field
- The documents also have a field `maxdistance`
- The location of the user is available in the variable `user.gps` as a GeoJSON point

The query currently looks like this:

```
query["location"] = {
     $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: user.gps,
      $maxDistance: filterDistance
    }
};
```

This query successfully selects all the datasets in a given `filterDistance` relative to the user.

What i'd like to have now is "If `document.maxdistance` field > 0 and the distance to the user is greater than `document.maxdistance`" do not select the dataset.

So i have documents that should not be found if the user lives in a distance greater than a given distance saved *inside* the document.

I don't know hot to express this in a mongodb query and i couldn't find any example of such a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$near/$nearSphere don't support per-document distance. Only per query. The main reason is sorting by distance. If you need only filtering you can use $geoIntersects/$geoWithin, but you will need to change documents to contain a polygon of the covered area, like a circle `Pi*2*distance` around it's location.

**Example:**

Assuming you have a document:

```
{
    loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10, 20 ] },
    distance: 10
}
```

So that it is returned when user's coordinate is within the radius, e.g. `[12, 25]`, and is not returned when user's coordinate is outside, e.g. `[12,30]`.

For that documents should be updated to convert `loc/distance` pair to a polygon. For the sake of simplicity I'll use octagon, but you may want to increase number of vertices for more accurate results:

```
{
    loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 10, 20 ] },
    distance: 10,
    area: {
        type : "Polygon",
        coordinates : [[ 
            [ 17, 27 ], 
            [ 10, 30 ], 
            [ 3, 27 ], 
            [ 0, 20 ], 
            [ 3, 13 ], 
            [ 10, 10 ], 
            [ 17, 13 ], 
            [ 20, 20 ], 
            [ 17, 27 ] 
        ]]
    }
}
```

Then you can use [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) to find documents which area includes user's coordinates:

```
db.collection.find({
    area: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: { type: "Point" , coordinates: [ 12, 25] }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell, how i would express the query with $geoWithin ? I still can't think of how to reference the documents field in the $geoWithin query. Can i use something like "$maxdistance" for the radius value of the $center operator ?

Comment: @Chris, I've added an example. I believe in your case $geoIntersect will work better than $geoWithin.